# Is there a better solution than Hadoop for simple O(n) complexity queries?

Tags: hadoop

I need to create a system, which is required to take terabytes of numerical data and answer three questions: 1. Min, 2. Max, 3. Total count

A friend suggested that Hadoop uses map-reduce where reduce step always sorts the data. This results in complexity of O(nlogn) even for O(n) queries such as min, max, and total count.

I have been searching on the internet; however, I have not been able to find an answer. Can some one please help? I am new to this field, so please bear with my lack of knowledge.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadoop does not change the asymptotic complexity of anything. It is merely about reducing the constant factor which big-O ignores.

There's always some overhead in putting together the results of a distributed computation. However in the case of your three problems, using a combiner will reduce the final sort to O(1). I don't know what the complexity is of the local sorting that happens on each map host for grouping for the combiner when there is only one key. It might be better than O(n lg n) in that case.

Comment: As you said: "Hadoop does not change the asymptotic complexity of anything." Just to be sure, this is true even for problems with complexity O(n)?

Comment: To implement, say, max, your mapper could only output a single record during the cleanup call.  Each map task would then be O(n), and finding the max of the local maxima would then be O(n) or better.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this in practice, but I believe you can effectively disable the sort by defining a custom sorting and grouping comparator for your job. You want to use a sorting comparator that says that all keys are equal for sorting purposes. I believe this will make all the sorts at least do as little work as possible -- one pass. You want to keep the default partitioner and grouping comparator though, so work is still distributed the same way, and the same values go with the same keys.

I don't know if this makes it O(n), since there is plenty of other stuff going on internally, like a merge.

And, big-O is a very crude measure of speed. Things like efficient writables and combiners will make a bigger difference than these issues.

Of course, I would probably not advise that you build custom MapReduce job for this kind of work. It's the kind of thing that Hive can answer for you, although it's just going to delegate to MapReduce jobs and will be slower than the simple MapReduce you contemplated at the beginning.

There are real-time-ish tools like Impala to answer these types of queries much, much faster. They don't use MapReduce, but do run on Hadoop. If you really want to do this, I'd strongly suggest looking in that direction.